# Как вывести количество комментариев?

Tags: php

На странице выводятся в цикле заметки с кратким описанием (заголовок, описание, автор, дата). Хочу добавить счетчик комментариев. Пробовал через `СOUNT(*)`, но так считает количество комментариев в первой заметке и проставляет такое же в остальных.

Вот код:

```
<?
//запрос в БД. Вытягиваю данные для краткого описания заметки
$result2 = mysql_query ("SELECT id, title, description, date, author, view FROM data WHERE cat='$cat' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $num",$db);
$myrow2 = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result2);

// запрос для вытягивания комментов
$result0 = mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM coments WHERE post=$myrow2[id]",$db);
$sum = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result0);

do {
printf("<table align='center' class = 'post'><tr><td>
<p class ='post_name'><a href='view_post.php?id=%s'>%s</a></p>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>%s<br><p class='post_view'>Дата добавления: %s | Просмотров: %s | Комментарии: %s</p>
</td>
</tr></table><br><br>",$myrow2["id"], $myrow2["title"],$myrow2["description"], $myrow2["date"], $myrow2["view"], $sum[0]);

}
while ($myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array ($result2));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ох жесть какая.

```
<?
$res_list = mysql_query ("SELECT id, title, description, date, author, view FROM data WHERE cat='$cat' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $num",$db);

while ($record = mysql_fetch_object($res_list)) do {
  $res_comments = mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM coments WHERE post=".$record->id.";",$db);
  $cc = mysql_fetch_object($res_comments);
?>
  <table align="center" class="post">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p class="post_name"><a href="view_post.php?id=<?=$record->id?>"><?=$record->title?></a></p>
      </td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <?=$record->description?>
        <br />
        <p class="post_view">Дата добавления: <?=$record->date?> | Просмотров: <?=$record->view?> | Комментарии: <?=$cc->C?></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br />
  <br />
<? } ?>
```

Разве так не симпатичнее?) Там, кстати, и ответ на ваш вопрос, разбирайте.